# Populate list with selecteditems from group of combo boxes

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I'm looping through a group of comboboxes in a container and I want to populate a list with the selected items in the comboboxes. How can I populate the list ?

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

foreach (var Cbox in CBoxContainer.Children.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
    if (Cbox.SelectedItem != null)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: there are no question at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just require a function to convert CBox.SelectedItem into Item, and add it to list.

```
Item ConvertToItem(Object obj)
{
  ....
}

foreach (var Cbox in CBoxContainer.Children.OfType<ComboBox>())
{
  if (Cbox.SelectedItem != null)
  {
   items.Add(ConvertToItem(CBox.SelectedItem));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items.Add(Cbox.SelectedItem);
```

I think you have created a class named `Item` and assigned ValueMemberPath and DisplayMemberPath as some properties of `Item` class.

```
myfirstcombobox.ValueMemberPath = "firstpropertyofItemclass"
myfirstcombobox.DisplayMemberPath = "secondpropertyofItemclass"
```

I came to this conclusion because the list you are creating like

```
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
```